# How to develop library for Web(React.js) and React Native as a single npm module?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, npm

I am trying to create a library that contains common components for `react` and `react-native`.I like to also publish it as a `npm` Module.

From the web there are several separate blogs on how to create an `npm` module for `web` and how to create an `npm` module for react-native.

But **not a single blog is there on how to publish a single npm module which contains 
both web and react-native modules**.

I am **only able to find  a single link** which the guy says he develops both libraries simultaneously but when i tried to install it i had to install it both separately(link below).

https://dev.to/kylessg/developing-npm-modules-for-web-and-react-native-simultaneously-with-webpack-3c36

**Is there any that i can publish as a single module** ?

Comment: had same question for over a year now!